Why exchange interaction only occur between particles with parallel spin?
I was reading and (still) trying to understand Hartree-Fock Theory. 
I read that exchange interaction only occurred between particles with parallel spin, and not the opposite spin, which is why there is no exchange in Helium, but there are in Carbon. 
Can someone please explain to me why that is? 

P.S. I've also read some explanations from other related posts, and I honestly still cannot figure it out.

AFAICT it's because parallel are indistinguishable - that's the main point of exchange interaction. BTW elements aren't proper nouns in English - why use capital letter for them?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112442/why-does-the-exchange-interaction-in-hartree-fock-theory-lower-the-total-energy
